# http post not going through, I don't think I am missing a parameter

Tags: android, html, forms, http-post

I need to be able to post the form at [http:///Default.aspx](http://customer.chuckwilson.com/Default.aspx) . I have tried I think all the different possible combinations of parameters that I thought I need to pass along, but I have not had any success.

I want to be able to post through an android code, but above that, I feel it is a problem with the request I am making for the post. Here is my code that attempts to post the form :

```
private void Post() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header

    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://customer.chuckwilson.com/Default.aspx");
    httppost.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0");
    httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    httppost.setHeader("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");
    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("__VIEWSTATE", "<state value>"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("__EVENTVALIDATION", "<Event validation value>"));

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtEmailAddress", "email@android.com"));

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtStreetAddress", "streetandroid"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtZipCode", "5454"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtCity", "cityandroid"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("CallBack", "rdCallBackYes"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtLastName", "lastandroid"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone", "(111) 111-1111"));

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        Log.d(getPackageName(), "executed http post req");
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
        if (resEntity != null) {    
            Log.i("RESPONSE",EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e(getPackageName(), "error1 in req");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e(getPackageName(), "error2 in req");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Everytime I run the code, the response I get is the html for that form. That indicates that my parameters are wrong, but I really don't see anything wrong with it. I hope someone can point the mistake/s out. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The form in the page you link to is defined with this HTML tag:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="Default.aspx" id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

The "enctype" means it is not using the URL-Encoded form submission that you are producing, but the MIME multipart protocol that's normally used for file uploads.

See this blog article, which shows how to use this type of form: http://blog.tacticalnuclearstrike.com/2010/01/using-multipartentity-in-android-applications/